# Why do I have an infinite loop when fetching user's geolocation in React?

Tags: reactjs, geolocation

I would like to fetch the user's geolocation in a React app. I have written this function:

```js
const fetchGeoLocation= () => {
  const [location, setLocation]= useState(null)
  const geo = navigator.geolocation
  if(!geo) return null
  const error = () => null;
  const success = (position) => setLocation([
    position.coords.latitude,
    position.coords.longitude,
  ]);
  geo.getCurrentPosition(success, error, {
    maximumAge: 10000,
  })
  return location
};
```

How to fix this?

Comment: your `return location` won't work as expected, given async nature of `SetLocation`, you would get an outdated value. where do you plan on use your return value? maybe add more of your code it will help to provide a more accurate answer.

as well you call a hook `useState` not at custom body which breaks the code. it should be defined at your component body.

Comment: So I've found the solution, I eventually passed a setState function as a parameter and used it in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole get geo logic (except `const [location, setLocation]= useState(null)` part) inside a `useEffect` hook with a `[]` to load it once

Comment: Thanks, the infinite loop is gone, but I can't click on a button to fetch the geolocation. Indeed, I receive an error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: well in this case change the `useEffect` to a simple function and return an `{location, getGeoFunction}`

Comment: I eventually passed a setState function as a parameter and used it in the success callback. Thanks for your help.